# Resistor ladder network component name

Tags: resistors, components, identification, component-selection, passive-components

Very basic question I'm sure

I am trying to buy components for a project I am doing, but I cant get the name of a component right yet.
But it has to exist somewhere.

I want a resistor array but instead of the resistors in parallel I want them in series with a point to take a measurement off after each resistor.

I have inserted a circuit if I have not been clear enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL5gXl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

.

Basically my idea is to have Vcc and GND on the end two pins and the take a voltage off after each resistor.
I'm using this to get an analog signal of the different voltage to select different settings in my micro processor.

I don't mind using just a bunch of resistors, but I would like it in a one package device for a neater board and a bit of space saving.

Any ideas of the name of the component ?

Comment: ah, I was worried that it could be something like that, Thanks Guess Ill just have to go for the extra parts and use a bunch of resistors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are generally called resistor networks. The specific type you are looking for is called a series network.

E.g.: [Bourns](http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/4300TSK.pdf?sfvrsn=52fae582_6)

[image]

Comment: The "isolated" variant can also be used in this case, by simply connecting the individual segments in series. I believe that the isolated variant is much more common, so this could still be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

They are often called "resistor networks" or "resistor arrays". The most popular types in SMT have 4 isolated resistors or have more resistors with a common (for pull-ups or pull-downs). In ultra-precision, dividers are common, but usually with only two resistors.

For example, for your shown 100 ohms, you could use one of [these](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/CTS%20Corporation%20PDFs/741%20to%20746%20Series%20Resistor%20Chip%20Arrays.pdf) parts (CTS  742C163101JP), and jumper the ends.

[image]

Personally, I prefer to use arrays of 4 isolated resistors because they can be used in many places- depending on your mounting cost they may be cost-effective even if one or two resistors remain unused or are connected in series or parallel to make a second value- for example you can get the equivalent of 4 0603 resistors in the space of one 1206. There are also much smaller parts if you like.

As the 4-resistor networks are quite popular, you will also have better luck if you are looking for tighter tolerance such as 1% or 0.1% rather than the usual 5% tolerance. The below parts (Vishay ACASA1000S1000P1AT) give you 4x 0.1% 100 ohm resistors for only about 50 cents a pack in 100's.

[image]